# How to convert each row of a column into a list of element?

Tags: r, string, list, dataframe

[image: column]

I need every row of this column to be a list. For example, first row to be a list with 1 element, second row with 1 element, third row with 3 element, forth row with 2 elements etc. I need to be able to access each element of these lists. Thank you

I tried everything on the internet but nothing works exactly how I needed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that will work by splitting each item at each `" "`

```r
where <- c("Intron", "CDS", "Intron Intron Intron", "Intron Intron", "Not close to gene")
strsplit(where, " ")
```

```
[[1]]
[1] "Intron"

[[2]]
[1] "CDS"

[[3]]
[1] "Intron" "Intron" "Intron"

[[4]]
[1] "Intron" "Intron"

[[5]]
[1] "Not"   "close" "to"    "gene"
```

**EDIT**

Example below allows "Not close to gene" and "Not translated" to stay together, and has output as a list of lists (as requested by question)

- It uses a negative lookup, so that " " followed by "translated", "close", "to", or "gene" won't but split.
- uses `lapply()` to apply `as.list()` to each row

```
where <- c("Intron", "CDS", "Intron Intron Intron", "Intron Intron", "CDS CDS Not translated Intron",  "Not close to gene")
lapply(
  strsplit(where, " (?!translated|close|to|gene)", perl = TRUE),
  as.list
)
```

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "Intron"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "CDS"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "Intron"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "Intron"

[[3]][[3]]
[1] "Intron"


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] "Intron"

[[4]][[2]]
[1] "Intron"


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] "CDS"

[[5]][[2]]
[1] "CDS"

[[5]][[3]]
[1] "Not translated"

[[5]][[4]]
[1] "Intron"


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] "Not close to gene"
```

Comment: I do need it together but there are more elements than these 5 and also I need to convert each row of the column into lists

Comment: There needs to be some rule by which you can split them. Does the space work to split them for all cases except for ‘not close to gene’ and ‘not translated’?

Comment: Ok see new example, which I think does what you want.